# Почему в  не отображаются кастомные VIew'ры?

Tags: android, прокрутка, view

Проблема такая. Есть `ScrollView`, в который вложен `LinearLayout` со всей программой. Всё отображается - фоны, кнопки, картинки, но вот свой класс, унаследованный от `SurfaceView` не выводится. С помощью логов убедился, что метод `onDraw` попросту не вызывается, и вручную не получается тоже - не могу получить тот самый `canvas` из `SurvaceHolder`.
При этом если я убираю этот самый скрол всё работает нормально. Почему так и как это решить? Программа - не список, поэтому `ListActivity` не покатит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё, проблема решена! Для тех кто с подобным столкнётся, решение вот. Нужно просто переопределить метод `onMeasure` и выставить конкретную ширину и высоту вьюшки с помощью `setMeasuredDimension`.